# DPDK segment fault in multi vmxnet3 devices

Tags: c, linux, vmware, dpdk

We're trying to run DPDK example dpdk-testpmd in a guest machine running Ubuntu 20.04. The host is ESXi version 6.5.

I'm building dpdk on the guest machine where I'm trying to run it. I've tried DPDK versions 21.11.1.

There are three virtual network devices, one for ssh, two for DPDK, all of them are use vmxnet3 driver.

```
## set kernel parameters
echo 1024 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
echo 1 > /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode
```

```
## bind dev
root@dpdk01:~/dpdk-stable-21.11.1/usertools# ./dpdk-devbind.py --status-dev net
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:0b:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' drv=vfio-pci unused=vmxnet3
0000:13:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' drv=vfio-pci unused=vmxnet3
Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:03:00.0 'VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller 07b0' if=eth0 drv=vmxnet3 unused=vfio-pci *Active*
```

```
# testpmd segment fault
root@dpdk01:~/dpdk-stable-21.11.1/build/app# ./dpdk-testpmd -l 0-3 -n 4
EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 1048576 kB hugepages reported
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Using IOMMU type 8 (No-IOMMU)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(3)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:0b:00.0 (socket 0)
EAL: Ignore mapping IO port bar(3)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_vmxnet3 (15ad:7b0) device: 0000:13:00.0 (socket 0)
testpmd: create a new mbuf pool <mb_pool_0>: n=171456, size=2176, socket=0
testpmd: preferred mempool ops selected: ring_mp_mc
Configuring Port 0 (socket 0)
Port 0: 00:0C:29:AE:03:68
Configuring Port 1 (socket 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

```
# gdb info
Thread 1 "dpdk-testpmd" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555930c0f in vmxnet3_write_mac.isra ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000555555930c0f in vmxnet3_write_mac.isra ()
#1  0x0000555555931e5c in vmxnet3_dev_start ()
#2  0x000055555624c6cc in rte_eth_dev_start ()
#3  0x00005555560e13d0 in start_port ()
#4  0x000055555597d98b in main ()
```

Comment: I suggest that you drop arguments `-l 0-3` and `-n 4` for a moment and run it with an exact NIC specifier argument: `./dpdk-testpmd -a 0000:0b:00.0 -- -i` (`-i` stands for interactive testpmd shell). If that doesn't work, consider trying the second NIC: `./dpdk-testpmd -a 0000:13:00.0 -- -i`. Are you still seeing the segfault?

Comment: @Dr.Zhu based on the GDB the seg fault pops up when a device tries to set the mac address. Checking the PMD code `vmxnet3_write_mac` internally calls `VMXNET3_WRITE_BAR1_REG`. So the easiest way to check the run the same with EAL option `--log-level=pmd,8` and re-run the same with `igb_uio instead of vfio-pci`/. My speculation is somehow vfio-pci is causing fault.

Comment: Thanks for @stackinside, I try to use single NIC, it is works, but when using two NICs, it is fault.

Comment: @VipinVarghese DPDK 21.11 doesn't compile igb_uio, so I try DPDK 18.11 and use igb_uio instead of vfio-pci, it works.

Comment: @Dr.Zhu Let's clarify, step by step: 1) Run it with single NIC `-a 0000:0b:00.0` = works? 2) Re-run it with single NIC but this time `-a 0000:13:00.0` = works? 3) Re-run it with two NICs by specifying `-a 0000:0b:00.0 -a 0000:13:00.0` on the same command line = works?

Comment: @Dr.Zhu igb_uio is no longer part of DPDK official release. You can use `git clone http://dpdk.org/git/dpdk-kmods` for the same. With respect to igb_uio and DPDK 18.11 it works means definitely there is something which is not compatible. What is the kernel version on the guest (vfio-pci)?